# In uTorrent, how to configure to (only) receive from encrypted peers?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, transmission

On Mac uTorrent has a setting for forcing encryption on outgoing traffic, but does not have one for (preferring) using encrypted incoming traffic, like Transmission does?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Under `Prefrences->BitTorrent` in the `Protocol Encryption` section uncheck the box for `Allow incoming legacy connections`

[image]

Comment: Mac Version 1.8.4 (29971) does not have the configuration setting window as you showed above.  It is like .